# Find similar filenames

Tags: shell, find, diff

How to find similar filename in linux commands?

For exemple:
I have similar files in diferent directories

```
dir1:
>     Imagine - John Lennon
>     Smells Like Teen Spirit, Nirvana

dir2:
>     John Lennon - imagine
>     Nirvana - smells like teen spirit
```

There are any way to search by similar words?

I think If had any thing that I could determine 80% of similarity, for instance

**Edit:**

I tried this work around:

```
find . -type f -name *.mp3 -printf "%f\n" > filelist
```

So, I upper case on text editor and, finally, I ran this command

```
cat filelist|cut -f1 -d/|sort|uniq -d
```

Comment: Are these all file names?

Comment: What have you tried? This Q will likely be voted closed because of  "asking for a tutorial" OR "too broad". Your Q needs to show specific code, with actual inputs, expected outputs, error messages and your thoughts about how you think it should work, v.s. how it is currently working. Read stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see what is expected for a Q here on StackOverflow. Good luck.

Comment: I tried this work around:

find . -type f -name *.mp3 -printf "%f\n" > filelist

So, I upper case on text editor and, finally, I ran this command

cat filelist|cut -f1 -d/|sort|uniq -d

Comment: Good that you updated your Q with your code. You can delete it from the comments now, right? ;-) ... I would use awk to capture each line of input, and then sort the words on the lines (and as you have done, convert to all upper (or lower) case. So you can compare `IMAGINE JOHN LENNON` from both. Unfortunately, making it so it will recognize partial matches and missing/extra entries is a bit more work. (I don't have the time to do it). Get that first part to work and repost a new Q. Good luck.